# Replace text in XSL using wildcards

Tags: xml, xslt

This is *similar* to an earlier problem I was having which you guys solved in less than a day.

I am working with XML files that are generated by a digital video camera. The camera allows the user to save all of the camera's settngs to an SD card so that the settings can be recalled or loaded into another camera. The XSL stylesheet I am writing will allow users to view the camera's settings, as saved to the SD card in a web browser.

While most of the values in the XML file -- as formatted by my stylesheet -- make sense to humans, some do not. What I would like to do is have the stylesheet display text that is based on the value in the XML file but more easily understood by humans.

A typical value that can be written to the XML file is "_23_970" which represents the camera's frame rate. This would be better displayed as 23.970 (or 023.970). The first underscore is a sort of place holder to make a space for values over 099.999. The second underscore, obviously represents the decimal.

My previous (similar) question involved replacing predictable text, and the solution was matching templates. In this case, however, the camera can be set at any one of 119,999 frame rates (I think I did that math correctly).

The approach, I would guess, is to pass a value to the displayed webpage that keeps the numeric values (each digit), replaces the second underscore with a decimal, and replaces the first underscore with either an nbsp or a zero (whichever is easier). If the first character in the string is a "1" (the camera can run at frame rates up to 120.000) then the one should be passed on to the page displayed by the stylesheet.

I have read other posts here regarding wildcards, but couldn't find one that answered this question.

EDIT: Sorry for leaving out important info. I fared better on my first try at asking a question! I guess I got complacent. Anyhow . . .

I should have shown you the code that displays the text in the XSL file as is:

```
<tr>
  <xsl:for-each select="Settings/Groups/Recording">
    <tr><td class="title_column">Frame Rate</td><td><xsl:value-of select="RecOutLinkSpeed"/></td></tr>
   </xsl:for-each>
</tr>
```

I should also have given you the URL for the sample file I have been working with: http://josephthomas.info/Alexa/Setup_120511_140322.xml

Comment: It would be helpful to see samples of these XML files.

Comment: I edited the original question to provide the information I should have provided in the beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use**:

```
concat(translate(substring(.,1,1), '_', '&#xA0;'),
       translate(substring(.,2), '_', '.')
      )
```

**Here is a complete transformation:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match=
  "td[preceding-sibling::*[1][self::td and . = 'Frame Rate']]/text()">
  <xsl:value-of select=
   "concat(translate(substring(.,1,1), '_', '&#xA0;'),
           translate(substring(.,2), '_', '.')
          )
   "/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on a simple XML document that contains one actual `tr` element (and one added to test the second case) from the actual XML document as pointed to by the provided link**:

```
<t>
    <tr>
        <td class="title_column">Frame Rate</td>
        <td>_23_976</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="title_column">Frame Rate</td>
        <td>118_235</td>
    </tr>
</t>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
<t>
   <tr>
      <td class="title_column">Frame Rate</td>
      <td> 23.976</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td class="title_column">Frame Rate</td>
      <td>118.235</td>
   </tr>
</t>
```

**Explanation**:

The expression:

```
concat(translate(substring(.,1,1), '_', '&#xA0;'),
       translate(substring(.,2), '_', '.')
      )
```

is evaluated in the following way:

1. The two arguments of the **[`concat()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#function-concat)** function are evaluated separately (independently from each other).
2. `concat()` does what it name implies -- concatenates its two string arguments into a single string.
3. The **[`translate()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#function-translate)** function is referenced twice in this expression -- it is used to produce each of the arguments of `concat().
4. The first call of `translate()` is: `translate(substring(.,1,1), '_', '&#xA0;')` . The first argument that is passed to the function in this case is the leading character of the string value of the current node (in XPath the current (or context) node is denoted by `.`). This leading character is produced by the function call: `substring(.,1,1)` which takes a **[substring](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#function-substring)** starting at offset 1 and having length of 1. The second argument to this call to `translate()` is a string containing all the characters that we want to replace or delete -- in this case just the single `"_"` character. The third argument to `translate()` is a string of "replacement characters" that should substitute the corresponding (by position) characters in the second argument. In this casethe third argument contains the single character `'&#xA0;'` (nbsp), this means that the call to the `translate()` function will replace the first character of the string value of the current node with nbsp *if* it happens to be an underscore.
5. The second call of `translate()` is similar to the first call: `translate(substring(.,2), '_', '.')` . However it is applied to the remainder of the current node's string value (starting from position 2) and replaces any underscore in this remainder with the dot character.

**Update**:

As the OP has difficulties in understanding how to adjust this solution to his own code. here is my guess (as his source XML doccument isn't the one pointed by the provided link and I cannot guess what the real XML document is):

```
<tr>
    <xsl:for-each select="Settings/Groups/Recording">
        <tr>
            <td class="title_column">Frame Rate</td>
            <td>
          <xsl:value-of select=
           "concat(translate(substring(RecOutLinkSpeed,1,1), '_', '&#xA0;'),
                   translate(substring(RecOutLinkSpeed,2), '_', '.')
                  )
           "/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
</tr>
```

Comment: Mr. Navatchev,
Not that I can truly make sense of the code, I get the general idea. What SEEMS to be missing, to me, is any reference to the original element in the XML file, which is "RecOutLinkSpeed". As you can tell in the few lines I copied from my XSL file is grouped under 
Settings/Groups/Recording
The text "Frame Rate" appears no where in the XML document, only in my XSL spreadsheet. I am ignorant, nearly, on XSL syntax, but it seems to me that any actions taken by code such as you have suggested must refer in some way to Settings/Groups/Recording/RecOutLinkSpeed.
No? (And thanks!)

Comment: Meanwhile I will search "concat(translate(substring" to try to get an understanding of the concat business.  :D

Comment: @JosephThomas: I don't apply the transformation on the whole XML document -- I just copied these two `tr` elements from the XML document (it needed slight corrections there was one `br` and one `hr` that were unclosed -- to make it well-formed). So the text "Frame Rate" *is* there. If you get the frame rate from another element -- this doesn't matter -- exactly the same code will be used in the body of the matching template.

Comment: @JosephThomas: As for the `concat()` function -- it is one of the basic standard XPath functions and is used very often in XSLT transformations. It can be passed any number of arguments and the result is the concatenation of their string values. As for `translate()` this is again a standard XPath function and it is used even more often than `concat()`. Read about `concat()` here:  http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#function-concat  and read about the `translate()` function here: http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#function-translate

Comment: @JosephThomas: The document pointed by the link you provided contains this: `<tr><td class="title_column">Frame Rate</td><td>_23_976</td></tr>` on line 47 when you follow the link with IE9 and then issue "View Source")

Comment: Alas, Mr. Navatchev, this is far beyond my understanding. As you found in my source-code (the XSL, not the XML) I am hacking away at this. I tried inserting your code into a local copy of my XSL but didn't see any effect. Am I correct in believing that your code modifies the XML file as opposed to simply causing the text to be displayed differently when viewed using the stylesheet? Perhaps this is one of those things that will only work on a server?
Thanks to another member here I was able to cause some of the text in the XML file to be displayed differently using the XSL file . . .

Comment: ....
    <xsl:template match="DteLut[. = 'Rec_Log']">
   <xsl:text>LogC</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

This worked for predictable values (it would be either on thing or another), but would not work (practically) when there are thousands of possible values.
I am ill-equipped to work out your code well enough to use it. The good news is if I leave it as is that anyone seeing _23_970 should be able to figure out that this means 23.970. I truly appreciate your time and effort, I'm just too dumb to sort it out!  Thanks again, sir.

Comment: @JosephThomas: If in your code `RecOutLinkSpeed` is what should be changed according to your rules, then simply replace the dot (`.`) in my answer with `RecOutLinkSpeed`. The big problem in your question is that you don't provide the real source XML document and the one your link points to is different from the one you are working with. If you provide a specific XML document (as small as possible) and the wanted result (don't include other requirements except the speed processing), I will give you the transformation that when applied on this document produces exactly the wanted result.

Comment: @JosephThomas: See the update to this answer. BTW my family name is N**o**vatchev -- not Navatchev.

Comment: Yes, the value of RecOutLinkSpeed is one of the values I would change. That value can be anywhere from 01.000 to 120.000. There are other elements in the XML file that have similar values, which I would also attack if I figure this out. The XML file in my link is the same XML file I am working with locally. My only edits are in the XSL file (other than adding <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="menustyle-v5-6.xsl"?>
to the second line of the XML file. 
I will give it another go with your code, substituting as suggested.

Comment: @ Dimitre Novatchev: Sorry for the misspelling! Are you unable to view the XML file in the link as source code?
http://josephthomas.info/Alexa/Setup_120511_140322.xml
I am working now with your update.

Comment: @JosephThomas: I am able to view the document, but the oncly occurence of "frame rate" gave me the `tr` I am working with in my answer: `<tr><td class="title_column">Frame Rate</td><td>_23_976</td></tr>`

Comment: @ Dimitre Novatchev: Yes! Your updated code did exactly as advertised. I believe I will be able to figure out how to apply the code to other such elements in the XML. Thank you, sir!
I'm sure this is "kid's stuff" to you, but as a non-programmer it makes my brain explode. When I finish my stylesheet than anyone using the camera in question should be able to view their setups in a browser. All that will be required of them is to add one line of text to their XML file and save my spreadsheet into the same folder as the XML file. Thank you not only for your help but for your patience!

Comment: @JosephThomas: I am glad that this answer was useful to you. Could you, please, *accept*  the answer (by clicking the check-mark next to it)?

Comment: @ Dimitre Novatchev: Oh, yeah! Forgot about the checkmark bit. I had just clicked "Yes" on the "useful" bit.  Shall I mention you in my stylesheet? You know, like an acknowledgement thing? Thanks again!

Comment: @JosephThomas: You are welcome. Feel free to do this, although I don't require anybody mentioning my help. And if something like this is mentioned in a blog post, I won't sue you :) If you are interested in my answers that I value most, take a look at them here: http://stackoverflow.com/users/36305/dimitre-novatchev?tab=favorites

Comment: @peter: I owe you a note of thanks, I think, in my stylesheet. Not that it will mean much to the camera people who might use it but it will mean something to me. 
To be honest, I don't fully understand the code, but I think I will be able to apply it to other elements of the XML.  I'm not trying to begin a new career, I'm doing this to help my fellow cameramen. 
But just to show that I'm not a total idiot, have a look at something I "engineered" back in 1999! 
http://goo.gl/bwIzP
You may also find it hard to believe that I wrote machine language code back in the 8-bit days. And sold it.

Comment: @JosephThomas: A machine language? Wow. For which computer? As for understanding the code, i'll put an explanation shortly.

Comment: @JosephThomas: I have added an explanation  -- just before the Update. Does this help in understanding the solution? If you still have hanging questions, please ask a new SO question and I will be glad to answer it.

Comment: The code I wrote -- back in the 80's -- was for the 6510 processor, which was in the Apple II and Commodore computers. Most of what I wrote would run on either, within an application suite called "GEOS," which was a sort of takeoff of the first Mac OS. I actually wrote in assembly language, which, of course, when assembled created the machine code. My "crowning achievement" was a "desktop accessory" called GetItWrite. But I was younger, then, and my brain worked better. As I get older it is harder and harder to learn new stuff.

Comment: @JosephThomas: Great stuff. In the 90's I was doing some computational linguistics stuff (machine morphology and a C implementation of Tomita's algorithm for parsing natural languages) and this remains some of the exciting things I have ever done. Then in 2000 I developed the FXSL library that implements support for functional programming (Higher-order functions) in XSLT 1.0 (later FXSL 2 -- for XSLT 2.0). If you haven't done functional programming I greatly recommend learning an FP language -- Haskell is a great one.

Comment: @PeterSmith: There is an English expression (I am guessing that you are Eastern European) that states, "You can't teach an old dog new tricks." Well, I'm the old dog in the expression!  :D

Comment: @JosephThomas: I guess PeterSmith has a lot to learn from an old dog :)

Comment: Geeze, how long have I been doing that? I hope Peter Smith has been enjoying your messages! Oh, well, it's easier to spell. (Don't I feel like an idiot!)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the element with those values is named `frame-rate` the following uses templates to handle to two cases:

```
<xsl:template match="frame-rate[starts-with(., '_')]">
  <xsl:value-of select="concat('&#160;', translate(substring(., 2), '_', '.'))"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="frame-rate[not(starts-with(., '_'))]">
  <xsl:value-of select="translate(., '_', '.')"/>
</xsl:template>
```